# How to reduce the size of my Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a couple of questions about what I might be able to do to reduce the size of my Access Database.

1. Do calculated fields in a Table take up more space than doing the calculations in a Query? For instance, I calculate Year, Month and Day in the tables, but could be doing this in the query instead, it just means more work every time I create a new query off those tables.
2. Does using lots of little queries increase the size vs all queries in one. For instance, I like to use 1 query for each baby step of the full process, joining 1 table at a time, so that I can track exactly where something might be going wrong, and be able to use each query at different steps if needed in another set of queries.

Are there any other good tips to keeping databases small in size? This general question will have definitely have been covered in many questions and blog posts, but I have tried roughly following them, but they don't seem to suit my database.

Thanks

Benji

Comment: Have you tried [compact/repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2)?  Split the data and the UI.   and yes storing the results of a calculated field will take up more space; but why is space such a concern?  Do you create/delete database structure objects and data often?  if so compact/repair can recover unused space!

Comment: I am reaching the 2GB limit. Compact and Repair is good, but I am having to do it too often.

Comment: What about splitting the UI, or have multiple databases with linked tables though performance will suffer.   Have you considered [upsizing to SQL server](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924)  maybe you're just grown to the point where you need a bigger engine as your backend!

Comment: By splitting the UI, that is only relevant if multiple users are going into Access, right? I am basically the only user that uses the database, and I don't have any forms, just tables and queries, and then link Excel connections to the queries and other people work off excel from there.

With having multiple databases, all the queries use all of the big tables in my DB, so if I have multiple databases linking to all the same tables, will this reduce size of each database?

Comment: Trust me, I have definitely thought and wished for SQL Server, but that would require tech set up, which is not feasible at the moment will our companies small tech capacity.

Comment: Well...  Sounds like you've done most of the typical activities.  Splitting the database so that the data is in one and the queries/reports are in another will buy you some more time as the data will reside in one, and the text for the queries/reports another.  It's not just for a multi user environment.  Are you storing any "attachment" files (.txt,.pdf,.xlsx .etc?) if so storing those on the file system with a link in the database would help as well.  You could as I said move data to different database files and use LINKED tables in one; but no integrity can be enforced on those tables.

Comment: OK, may give splitting up the database into multiples a try.

But just to confirm, having calculated fields on the tables takes up more space than writing them into queries?

Comment: yes, the calculated field is stored and updated each time the record is changed.  thus taking up more space.  but at a savings during execution of queries and what not.  So you're giving up performance for space.  most people go the other way (what you already have) in today's world.  (1970-80's... different story.)